# Problem with registration page

Tags: user-registration

I am sorry if this is a very trivial question, but I am very new to wordpress and this is the first time I use wp.
I am trying to set a website with wordpress and buddypress. I followed all the steps and the website is up and running in my localhost. Now I would like that a new members can register in the website. When I try to go to registration page server tell me that the page does not exist. I googled for a while, but I did not found any basic tutorial. Then I believe that this is a very trivial question, so I am wondering if something goes wrong during the installation. Who can help me or give me a resource to fix this problem?

Comment: Please write your solution into the answer field, and accept that answer then. Do not put the solution into the question, and do not use some arbitrary to indicate a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the mod_rewrite of Apache. I went in  `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default`  and I changed

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
allow from all
```

to

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride all
Order allow,deny
allow from all
```

the I restarted the apache server and all gone fine.